# Change css class on @click event of a table responsive table

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I would love to change the background color on a row in a table when i click on the `tr`.

That's the code of the table:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><small class="text-muted">#</small></th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Heading</th>
                    <th>Productor</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr
                    v-for="company in allCompanies"
                    :key="company.id"
                    role="button"
                    @click="selectCompany(company)"
                >
                    <td class="text-primary">
                        <small>#{{ company.id }}</small>
                    </td>
                    <td class="fw-bold">{{ company.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ company.heading }}</td>
                    <td>
                        {{ company.productor }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

And here the code of the method I call on the click event:

```
 selectCompany(company) {
        this.storeSelectedCompamy(company);
        this.fetchShows(company.id);
        console.log("change css");
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Valerio

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

It looks like each `<tr>` corresponds to a `company`, so my approach would be to attach each row's state to its corresponding `company` as a property, and then toggle that property in `selectCompany`. Something like:

```
selectCompany(company) {
  allCompanies.forEach(_company => _company.isSelected = false);
  company.isSelected = true;
}
```

```
<tr
  v-for="company in allCompanies"
  :key="company.id"
  :class="company.isSelected ? 'selected' : ''"
  role="button"
  @click="selectCompany(company)"
>
```

Comment: I like your solution but I see 2 problems: 1st, I lose the :hover color, 2nd seems doesn't work..maybe I made some mistakes

Comment: Losing the `:hover` color is due to the `style` attribute overriding your CSS. Using a class should fix that problem. I've updated my code. As for it not working, that could be for any number of reasons. Can you provide a code snippet to work with?

Comment: Sorry but I've a poor English...what do you exactly mean with "code snippet"? If a paste a full code of the .vue file would be enougth? Thank you for your help

Comment: No, not a `.vue` file. On StackOverflow a "snippet" is a piece of code that StackOverflow will run. It makes it much easier to answer questions. Here's more info: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/